# Disable drop if div has already been dropped?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I've created a drag and drop game in order to start teaching myself jquery. Everything seems to be working but you can drop more than one item onto the same square. I want to disable droppable if the place holder has an image in it.

I've looked into:

```
`greedy: true`
```

That disables the drop but I'm not sure how to enable it again and also:

```
$(this).droppable( 'disable' );
```

I can get these both to disable the drop but not sure how I get them to enable it again if the block/image reverts back to its original position or is moved to another square.

Full version:
http://creativelabel.co.uk/drag-and-drop/

UPDATE:
This is the code for the droppable slots.

```
  for ( var i=0; i<=19; i++ ) {
  var images = 'images/slot' + slotNumbers[i] + '.jpg';
$('<div class="placeholder"><div class="img-slot"></div></div>').attr('id', 'slot'+slotNumbers[i]).data( 'slotNumbers', slotNumbers[i] ).appendTo( '#imgSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#images img',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleDropEvent,
      activate: handleDragEvent
});
```

This is `drop:` event code:

```
  function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'slotNumbers' );
  var imgNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );
  ui.draggable.addClass( 'dropped' );
  $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
  ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'right top', at: 'right top' } );

  if ( slotNumber == imgNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'img-match' );
    ui.draggable.data("valid", true);

    imgMatch++;
  }  else {
      if(ui.draggable.data("valid")) {
         imgMatch--;
         ui.draggable.data("valid", false); 
      }
  }
```

The `activate:` code:

```
  function handleDragEvent( event, ui ) {
   $(this).droppable( 'enable' );
   if(ui.draggable.data("valid")) {
         imgMatch--;
         $('input[name=Score]').val(imgMatch);
         $('#score h1').text(imgMatch);
         ui.draggable.data("valid", false); 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-disabled)(Look under "methods" tab) indicate that to disable you use:

```
$(this).droppable( 'disable' );
```

And to enable you use

```
$(this).droppable( 'enable' );
```

---

Update: Check this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/QqJRs/
Drag one of the red squares to the big box and drop it (it turns green to indicate its dropped). You cant drop any of the others to this box while one is inside.
Now drag that one out (It turns back red to indicate its removed). Now you can drop any of the others in its place.

The crux of this is as I described in my comment below; when you drop an item in a container associate the container with the item:

```
drop: function(event,ui){
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'dropped' ); // taken from your code & I used to change color

   ui.draggable.data('droppedin',$(this)); // associate the container
    $(this).droppable('disable'); // disable the droppable
}
```

Then when you drag it again, unassociate and re-enable:

```
drag: function(event,ui){
       if($(this).data('droppedin')){
           $(this).data('droppedin').droppable('enable'); v// re-enable
           $(this).data('droppedin',null);  // de-associate
           $(this).removeClass( 'dropped' ) // remove class
       }
   }
```

Comment: Well, seeing as you've not posted any code (And no, im not sifting through your entire codebase in your link) it's a bit hard to comment on where to put this in your code. Try to narrow down where you *think* you should enable the `droppable` and update your question with relevant code sections

Comment: Ok I've updated my question as to where I think the enable should go. The activate code takes one off the score if the user drags a square onto another so to me that seems like a logical place to put the enable code?

Comment: I have tried it. It disables the drop if an image is already dropped on a square so I can't put another image on top of it, works as I want it. The image reverts back or I drag it to another square then the slot it was previously in doesn't accept drops any more, meaning the enable doesn't enable again.

Comment: Finding information on dropped disable is easy, enable not so. What I can't get my head around is how I target the image Slot to enable the drop again on image drag?

Comment: When a item is dropped in a slot, assocaite the slot with the item. When that item is dragged outside its slot, re-enable the slot and dis-associate.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know null would de-associate it from the slot. Thanks for your help, learning a lot just by getting on and coding.

Comment: Its not the null that de-associates it per-se, but thats just so that the test above it `if($(this).data('droppedin'))` returns falsey next time.