# Disable image drop if an image has already been dropped?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

i have the same question like,
I have two div tags in which i want to drag image from dynamically created list of images.
But i want to restrict another image to be drag on same div.

[Disable drop if div has already been dropped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639533/disable-drop-if-div-has-already-been-dropped)

I used the method told in its answer by Jamiec.

But, heres the problem i got an error which i unable to solve

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'originalPosition' of undefined

Please somebody help me in removing this error.

Comment: could you please share the code on jsfiddle.

Comment: @Mahesh Sapkal sure.. check it. jsfiddle.net/sJR8k

Comment: @Mahesh Sapkal  here i want to restrict element from dropping if there is already an element exist or replace the first dropped element with second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option: #1

Please check the demo. Element will always revert back to it's original position if there is already an element dropped over droppable.

```
$('#target').droppable({
    accept: ".dragme",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
       ui.draggable.addClass('dropped');
       ui.draggable.draggable( "disable" );
      $('#target').droppable( "option", "accept", "" );
    }
});

$('.dragme').draggable({
    revert : 'invalid'
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/4GmBT/3/)**

## Option: #2

Here's another demo, where in when an new element is dropped the existing dropped element will revert back to it's original position.

```
var droppedObj = null;
$('#target').droppable({
    accept: ".dragme",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if(droppedObj !== null) {
            droppedObj.animate({ left: '0px', top : '0px', opacity : 1 }, 200).removeClass('dropped');
            droppedObj.draggable("enable");
        }
        droppedObj = ui.draggable;
        ui.draggable.addClass('dropped').draggable("disable");
    }
});

$('.dragme').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/B2Y3R/)**